# Is it possible to connect docker linux to docker on windows?

Tags: windows, docker, ubuntu, networking, docker-swarm

I have 2 computers.

- One on ubuntu 18.04
- One on windows 10
  I have docker installed on both of them.
  I create a swarm between the two but I am not able to
  create an overlay network over the two of them.

1. Is it possible to connect docker linux and docker windows ?
2. Plus I would like to know if it's possible for me to run
   Mongodb container on windows and linux and make them communicate together ?

I intend to build a mongodb sharded cluster.

Comment: Docker Desktop or Docker EE on the windows 10? But really it should work. Probably a windows firewall issue.

Comment: Docker Desktop on windows 10.

Comment: If you successfully created a Swarm between the two Docker hosts, then the ingress overlay network should already exist by default: https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/. Check to see if "ingress" is listen when you run `docker network ls`